# Can I make this code more efficient? It currently takes ~6 hours to run on ~1m entries

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have 2 `DataFrames`:

1. `trips_df` total entries = 1,048,568

[image]

2. `weather_df` total entries = 2,654

[image]

I am trying to calculate and attach the `total_precipitation` for each trip as a column. I do this by looking up the `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` datetime for each trip from the `trips_df`, in the `weather_df`, and summing the `precipitation_amount` within those times, then attaching that value back in the `trips_df` under the new column.

Code used to do this:

```py
def sum_precipitation(datetime1, datetime2, weather_data):

    time1_rd = datetime1.replace(minute=0, second=0)
    time2_ru = datetime2.replace(minute=0, second=0) + dt.timedelta(hours=1)

    if time1_rd in set(weather_data['start_precipitation_datetime']):

        start_idx = weather_data.start_precipitation_datetime[
            weather_data.start_precipitation_datetime==time1_rd].index[0]

        if time2_ru in set(weather_data['end_precipitation_datetime']):

            end_idx = weather_data.end_precipitation_datetime[
                weather_data.end_precipitation_datetime==time2_ru].index[0]

            precipitation_sum = weather_data.iloc[start_idx:end_idx+1, 7].sum()

        else: precipitation_sum = 0
    else: precipitation_sum = 0

    return round(precipitation_sum, 3)

def join_weather_to_trips(trips_data, weather_data):

    trips_weather_df = trips_data.copy()

    fn = lambda row : sum_precipitation(row.start_timestamp, row.end_timestamp, weather_data)
    col = trips_data.apply(fn, axis=1)
    trips_weather_df = trips_weather_df.assign(total_precipitation=col.values)

    return trips_weather_df


trip_weather_df = join_weather_to_trips(trips_df, weather_df)
```

I ran the code on a subset of 65 entries and it took ~1.3s. (`CPU times: user 1.27 s, sys: 8.77 ms, total: 1.28 s, Wall time: 1.28 s`). Extrapolating that performance to my entire data, it would take (1.3 * 1048568)/65 = 20971.36seconds or 5.8hours.

Can someone with more experience tell me if I'm doing this correct, where I could speed this code up, or if there are any alternatives (e.g. faster implementations)?

Comment: I think that you’d gain a lot of speed if you loaded this in an SQL database and create an SQL query for that.

Comment: At first glance, I observed that you're forming a `set` based on `start_precipitation_datetime` and `end_precipitation_datetime` for every row in the `trips_df`. Instead you can form the sets initially, and pass them in `sum_precipitation`.

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci Wow... now it computes in 133ms instead of 1.3s for the subset (35min instead of 6h for the entire table). Thank you.

Comment: @muka.gergely Thanks for the idea, I'll keep this in my for the future

Comment: Just to make sure, the precipitations amount comes in every hour?

Comment: @QuangHoang No the data is not constant, as in, the precipitation will be every hour for n-rows (example), then jump 5 hours ahead, then be constant for another n-rows

Comment: Mind posting your df as text rather than images?

Comment: @Bn.F76 I know SQL doesn’t solve your problem right now. The other thing you could do (besides optimizing your algorithm) is data preparation. This means you transform your current data that better fits your future goals: e.g. I’d first add helper fields (columns) to store years, months, days, and hours separately (no minutes, as in your algorithm you modify minutes to 0). This gives a lot of overhead in terms of database size, but much faster querying. Or you could just create two new datatables that only contain data that you’re going to use.

Comment: @Bn.F76 Or you could halt your algorithm, when you know you extracted enough hours from the precipitation table - you store the duration of the trips, so you know how many records you need to sum up (0-1 hour trip is 1 record, 1-2 hours require 2 records, etc.) If you halt your algorithm when it summed up enough records, it doesn’t need to scan the million records again.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the fastest, but you could try:

```
trips_df['precipitation_amount'] = 0

for s,e,p in zip(weather_df['start_precipitation_datetime'], 
               weather_df['end_precipitation_datetime'],
               weather_df.precipitation_amount):
    masks = trips_df.start_timestamp.between(s,e) | trips_df.end_timestamp.between(s,e)
    trips_df.loc[masks, 'precipitation_amount'] += p
```

On my computer, it took 10s to process 1M trips and 260 weathers. So about 100s for the actual data.

Update: I did try on 1M trips and 2600 weathers, `Wall time: 1min 36s`

**Note**: You may need to reduce `weather_df['end_precipitation_datetime']` by one minute to avoid double counts in case the trip starts on the hour.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `pip install DateTimeRange`

```
start_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 20, 30)
end_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 20, 30)
start_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 20, 30)
end_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 22, 30)
dtr1 = datetimerange.DateTimeRange(start_1, end_1)
dtr2 = datetimerange.DateTimeRange(start_2, end_2)
```

Then, if you want to check if dtr1 is contained in dtr2:

```
>>> dtr1.start_datetime in dtr2
True
>>> dtr1.end_datetime in dtr2
True
```

That way, you save a lot of "if, then".

By the way, I am not sure if you should be using "set", why not:

```
weather_data['start_precipitation_datetime'].values
```

Comment: Is there any performance gain in using `DateTimeRange` rather than the ifs and elses? Also, `.values` and `set()` dont do the same thing.. the latter has no duplicates .The counterpart would be `np.unique(...)`